# parseLong Numberformat exception 7.7

Tags: android, parsing, android-edittext, long-integer

I'm retrieving a number from EditText:

```
long org=0;
String EnteredOrgAmount=amount.getText().toString();

if(!EnteredOrgAmount.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
    org=Long.parseLong(EnteredOrgAmount);
}
```

This works fine, until I enter 7.7 for example, the I get a numberFormatException. I can't use the comma, since I declared the EditText in XML as:  `android:inputType="numberDecimal"`

Is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: You can use float instead of long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of parsing in Long parse in Double and if you have need only long value then parse in double and store in long value

```
double org=0;
String EnteredOrgAmount=amount.getText().toString();

if(!EnteredOrgAmount.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
    org=Double.parseDouble(EnteredOrgAmount);
}
```

For long just declare org as long instead of double

```
long org=0;
String EnteredOrgAmount=amount.getText().toString();

if(!EnteredOrgAmount.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
    org=(long)Double.parseDouble(EnteredOrgAmount);
}
```